Como puedo borrar las carpetas y archivos de temp y papelera de Windows usando wsl kali linux y bash?
Estoy creando un script de Bash para automatizar el borrar los archivos y carpetas de temp y papelera de Windows. Claro estoy usando kali linux desde wsl, este es mi código:
Código:
#!/bin/bash
# Limpiador automatico de temp y papelera

echo "Limpia tu papelera y temp de forma automatica"
read -p "temp o papelera?: " respuesta

if [[ respuesta == "temp" ]]; then

    cd C:\Users\Bradalis\AppData\Local\Temp
    rm -rf *

elif [[ respuesta == "papelera" ]]; then

    cd powershell -command "Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\$Recycle.Bin' -Recurse | Format-Table -Property FullName, LastWriteTime"
    rm -rf *

else
    echo "Ocurrio un error"
fi

Para poder ejecutar el script desde Windows lo hago con este comando:
wsl bash -c "/bin/script.sh"

El problema es que me muestra el mensaje de Ocurrio un error, es decir, que no pudo borrar nada, cuando pongo temp como respuesta, pero si pongo papelera no me muestra nada como si no funcionaran los comandos que puse.
Que debo hacer, cual seria el error?

¿Y revisaste el estado de la papelera antes y después de ejecutar?

Si bien cumple con lo de automatizar, el propio Windows desaconseja utilizar WSL para hacer uso intensivo de archivos montados en Windows porque es más lento. Si solo necesitas los comandos más comunes de Bash, considera utilizar Git Bash. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68972448/

Hay varias cositas aquí. La mas importante es que haces rm -rf *, !sin primero averiguar que conseguiste cambiar de directorio! Entonces, si por cualquier razón el cd falló, vas a borrar todo el contenido del directorio actual, probablemente tu $HOME. Mala idea. En todo caso, no hace falta el cd, puedes borrar directamente con rm C:\Users\Bradalis\AppData\Local\Temp\*, si el WSL es capaz de entender el C:\Users\Bradalis\AppData\Local\Temp, cosa que no se ya que no uso WSL.
En todo caso, no hace falta el cd ya que o bien WSL entiende cosas como C:\foo o no, y si lo entiende, puedes rm C:\foo\* y sino, no puedes ni si quiera hacer cd. Pero mirando un poco la documentación de WSL y otras preguntas online, me parece que quieres /mnt/c/Users/Bradalis/AppData/Local/Temp/.
Después, es generalmente mala idea pedir texto de tu usuario. Aun mas si pides un string con muchas letras. Es muy fácil equivocarse, y no se puede automatizar. Mucho mejor y mas cómodo pasar argumentos al script al momento de lanzarlo.
Ahora, tu script falla porque estas comparando el string respuesta y no la variable que sería $respuesta. Ademas, intentas hacer cd powershell que no tiene sentido ya que powershell es un comando y no un directorio. Imagino que powershell -command ... es un comando que te da la ubicación de tu papelera de Windows. Si quieres usar la salida de un comando como argumento para otro, necesitas comando1 "$(comando2)", no puedes simplemente hacer comando1 comando2.
Entonces, probablemente quieres cd "$(powershell -command ...)". Pero como dije antes, no hace falta el cd, y puedes hacer rm $(powershell ...) o guardar la salida del comando en una variable y usar ella con rm "$papelera"/*.
Algo como:
#!/bin/bash
# Limpiador automatico de temp y papelera

respuesta=$1

if [[ "$respuesta" == "temp" ]]; then
    rm -rf /mnt/c/Users/Bradalis/AppData/Local/Temp/*

elif [[ "$respuesta" == "papelera" ]]; then

    papelera=$(powershell -command "Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\$Recycle.Bin' -Recurse | Format-Table -Property FullName, LastWriteTime")
    ## solo quieres borrar si has conseguido encontrar la papelera
    if [ -n "$papelera" ]; then
        rm -rf "$papelera"/*
    fi
else
    echo "Ocurrio un error"
fi

Ahora, lanza el script con
wsl bash -c "/bin/script.sh papelera"

o
wsl bash -c "/bin/script.sh temp"

